# простое получение mac адреса

Tags: python

Имеем компьютер подключенный к сети через ip телефон. 
Необходимо получить mac адрес этого телефона.
Идея в том, чтобы написать программу (скорее всего она будетнаписана на питоне) которая будет собирать и отправлять в базу три параметра:

- Кто залогинился в компьютер
- Какой телефон подключен к компьютеру
- В какой группе AD состоит пользователь.

Вся эта информация должна собираться и отправляться в базу при каждом логине.
 Вопрос только по сбору мака подключенного телефона. Мне не нужен полноценный снифер, нужен только один параметр из фрейма, как это лучше написать не раздувая код программы?

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но, скорее всего, останется без ответа. ip-телефон для даунлинка является обыкновенным свитчем и, соответственно, прозрачен для пакетов (не учитывается в списках хопов). Поэтому, со стороны клиента вы его не вычислите. Единственное, что приходит в голову - это, при наличии доступа к ближайшему маршрутизатору получать порт, на котором светится мак-адрес ПК пользователя, и смотреть, какой еще мак-адрес на этом порту. с большой долей вероятности, это и будет мак-адрес телефона. но не со 100%. В общем, даже в таком случае очень много "но" остается.